# iOS return key - login action

Tags: ios, authentication, keyboard-events

I have a Username/email and password Field with a login button on a login page. When user is in password field, the keyboard is shown with a return key. How do I set that return key to make the same action as the Login button so the user doesn't need to close keyboard and touch Login button?

```
class LoginScreen: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var errorMessage: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(JournalEntryViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {

    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}




@IBAction func loginUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginComplete", sender: self)


    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(userName.text!, password: password.text!) {

        (user, error) in

    if error != nil{

        self.errorMessage.text = "Please check email and password"

    } else {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginComplete", sender: self)

    }
```

I have looked at some similar posts, but am not quite getting it.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without coding you can achieve this easily by joining "Did End On Exit" Event of the UItextfield to the IBAction of the particular UIViewController as shown in figure.

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using this function which will call the login function when the enter button is pressed on the keyboard.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == self.passwordTextField {
        loginAction(textField)
    } else {
        self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

//textField code

 if textField == self.passwordTextField {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()  //if desired
    performLogin()
   }

    return true
}

func performLogin() {

////   Login methods
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

use textfield‘s delegate，to custom your return key

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == self.passwordTextField {
        self.loginUser(textField)
    } else {
        self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
return true
}
```